# Inflating Fragment on Demand

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a `Fragment` hosting a lot of `Views` inside. Currently, however, I intend to hide those `Views` unless certain conditions are met, and let the `Fragment` display some placeholder text.

I am currently just using a `FrameLayout` with an **overlay** for that `Fragment` that will have its **visibility** set to **GONE** if the conditions are met, but this solution isn't exactly optimal.

Is there a way to inflate the contents of the `Fragment` **on demand**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like [`ViewStub`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewStub.html) is what you're after.

See [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/loading-ondemand.html) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Spent some time trying it out and it works now :)